# How to remove an attachMorph of HandleMorph in smalltalk from self

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, gnu-smalltalk

i need your help
i am creating a line from a spesific location to mouse location with this code.
after click i am trying to remove this line but i have no idea how
please help me remove the live after click what should i change ?

```
stk:=  (LineMorph from: 100@100 to: 1300@1300 color: Color red width: 2) openInWorld.
handle := HandleMorph new forEachPointDo:  [:newPoint | stk setVertices: {whiteBallinHole position. (newPoint-(10@10)). }.
stk on: #mouseDown send: #value: to:[:evt|
    evt redButtonPressed ifTrue:[  self handlesMouseDown:  evt.
```

"DELETE THE STICK AFTER MOUSE CLICK THIS DOSNT WORK PLEASE HELP"

```
stk color: Color transparent.
stk delete.
```

""

```
 ].
    ].
    ]. 
    " (self  currentHand attachMorph: handle)."
    " self currentHand addMorph:handle. "
    self currentHand attachMorph:handle.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is a bit of a mess. One thing that is out of place is

```
self handlesMouseDown: evt.
```

That is supposed to return true if you want to receive mouseDown: messages. 
In a workspace, that self does not exist. And the result is never used. Just delete it. The resulting code would be something like

```
whiteBallinHole := CircleMorph new openInWorld .
stk := (LineMorph 
    from: 100@100 to: 1300@1300 
    color: Color red 
    width: 4) openInWorld.
handle := HandleMorph new forEachPointDo: [ :newPoint | 
stk setVertices: {whiteBallinHole center. (newPoint-(10@10)). }.
stk on: #mouseDown send: #value: to: [:evt|
    evt redButtonPressed ifTrue:[
        stk color: Color transparent.
        stk delete]]].
self currentHand attachMorph: handle.
```